# How to unsubsubscribe from observable in Angular component on route change?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 2 routes -> `intro` and `start`. Each route uses the same `scrolling-component`.  How do I clean up (unsubscribe(?)) from my `Observable.fromEvent()` when I switch from route `intro` to `start`?

Scrolling to snap effect happening in my Angular application, shown here:

```
  public scrolling() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      Observable.fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'scroll')
        .debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe((e: Event) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.changeSubject.next();
          });
        },
      );
    });
    this.changeSubject.subscribe((): void => {
      this.snap();
    });
  }

  private snap() {
    const y = Math.round(this.host.nativeElement.scrollTop /
      this.optionItemHeight) *
      this.optionItemHeight;
    this.host.nativeElement.scrollTo({
      top: y,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }
```

How do I clean up the Observable when I change the route?

Answer (score 2):

Assign it to a class variable then unsubscribe during the OnDestroy cycle

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.something.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: what is the type of this.x = Observable.fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'scroll');  wont there be 2 observables here?

Comment: well changeSubject.next() just emmits the next observable. You either want to unsubscribe from this.changeSubject, so you could do something = this.changeSubject. Then you could do this.something.unsubscribe(), OR (and I say or cuz i'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish) you could create the observable differently, so for example instead of Observable.fromEvent you could do const observable = new Observable(observer => { rest of code...).debounceTime....etc. Let me know if you need an example